# S2 Geo Functions in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, geolocation, geospatial, geocoding, s2

I'm just wondering if there is any plans to add functions for the S2 geo library into BigQuery?

Seems like surely lots of people have lat-long data in BQ - some s2 functions to got to cells and back etc would be super useful surely - happy to file a feature request if there is not already one.

Best links i could find as fyi:

http://blog.christianperone.com/2015/08/googles-s2-geometry-on-the-sphere-cells-and-hilbert-curve/
https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/geo/s2
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Hl4KapfAENAOf4gv-pSngKwvS_jwNVHRPZTTDzXXn6Q/view

I do see some javascript libraries but not sure if they can be used in UDF's

https://www.npmjs.com/package/s2-geometry
https://github.com/mapbox/node-s2

I wonder is it the sort of thing that one could do just in UDF's?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BigQuery team is interested in adding some sort of support for geo-spatial operations - so the more information you can provide about your use cases - will better inform the planning and prioritization.
In the meantime, S2 library is indeed used extensively inside Google with much success, including as UDFs inside BigQuery. I was not aware of public port to JavaScript that you linked above - but I believe it should be possible to take advantage of it inside BigQuery JS UDFs.

**Update**: BigQuery GIS has shipped: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-intro

Answer (score 2):

As Mosha said, it is possible to take advantage of BigQuery JS UDFs.

You can take a look at the github project [jslibs](https://github.com/CartoDB/bigquery-jslibs) or use directly the code below as an example.

```
SELECT `jslibs.s2.ST_S2`(longitude_centroid, latitude_centroid,5)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.worldpop.population_grid_1km`
WHERE last_updated = "2017-01-01"
LIMIT 1000
```

disclaimer: I am one of the contributors to this project.

Comment: This is what I need exactly. May I learn how can I implement the JS file in the BQ, and use the `jslibs.s2.ST_S2` as you shown?

Comment: `jslibs.s2.ST_S2` is a public JS UDF, so it should run direcly from your BigQuery account. To include a JS file in bigquery, look at the following documentation. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#including-javascript-libraries

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery geospatial functions added two native functions for working with S2 cells:

```
S2_CELLIDFROMPOINT(point_geography[, level => cell_level])

S2_COVERINGCELLIDS(
    geography
    [, min_level => cell_level]
    [, max_level => cell_level]
    [, max_cells => max_cells]
    [, buffer => buffer])
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#s2_cellidfrompoint
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#s2_coveringcellids

That said, one typically should use regular `ST_*` set of functions for most geospatial tasks, but S2 functions could be helpful for advanced workload or interoperability with other systems using S2.